# How to hide the scroll bars of a WebBrowser Component and maximize its height

Tags: codenameone

I'm trying to create a composition of `Label`s and a `WebBrowser`component which will contain some html text. But the composition itself should be scrollable vertically. Currently the `WebBrowser`component itself is scrollable and shows scrollbars which is not intended. The `WebBrowser` should have max height and when I swipe on the `WebBrowser` the whole composition should be slided instead. How can I manage this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That might be problematic in reality partially because of what you see here but also because of the complexities related to peer components. Peer components work in a completely different space from Codename One lightweight components. So they expect to scroll themselves and handle their own space.

This means that if you swipe to scroll the peer will try to scroll itself while the surrounding elements will try to scroll the whole `Form` and you will end up with a mess on your hands.

Even if this worked you would have a performance nightmare as peer components carry an overhead. It's not a problem to pay it once per form but doing it over and over might bog down an app completely.

I would suggest trying to [customize this approach](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/tip-lightweight-rich-text-view.html).

Comment: unfortunately the rendering of such a RichtTextView is not performant since the more words are in the text the more `Label`s are created. I tested it on a device and the sliding is really slow :/. But concerning my use case it's a step towards the goal.

Comment: If performance is a concern this approach will be worse. Make sure the parsing only happens once and try to minimize the usage of this. E.g. if there are cases where no styling is used then use TextArea.